# How to avoid Thread.sleep(700) method on selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, lombok

I use Thread.sleep(700) method on my test because selenium is too fast. The website elements aren't loaded.
Code:

```
private By searchInput = By.xpath("//input/parent::div/*");
 @SneakyThrows
  public Seminar searchSeminarByName(String seminarName){
      WebElement searchInp = driver.findElement(searchInput);
      if (searchInp == null){
          log.error("Can not find element by {}", searchInput);
      }else{
          log.info("Founded element ex {}", searchInp);
          log.info("Founded element {}", searchInp.getTagName());
      }

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
      searchInp.click();
      Thread.sleep(500); //Required waite, because "sendKeys" is ignored for some time after render.
      searchInp.sendKeys(seminarName);
      Thread.sleep(700);
    searchInp.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
      Thread.sleep(700);

      WebElement seminarId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]"));
      WebElement seminarNametd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]"));
      WebElement seminarStatus =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[4]"));

      return new Seminar(Long.parseLong(seminarId.getText()), seminarNametd.getText(),seminarStatus.getText());
  }
```

**Detail:**
**Junit:**

```
@Test
    public void searchFieldCheck(){
        Seminar seminar = seminarPage.searchSeminarByName(groupName);
        Assert.assertEquals(groupName, seminar.getName());
    }
```

**Log without using Thread.sleep(700):**
Starting ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}) on port 10816
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
февр. 04, 2021 5:05:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2021-02-04 17:05:20.104 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element ex [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (6519d001ef8f6f9cd885780373e8d003)] -> xpath: //input/parent::div/*]
2021-02-04 17:05:20.111 [main] INFO  SeminarPage - Founded element input

org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
Expected :Gtest
Actual   :DSem31

Comment: what happens if you don't add the sleep will it throw exception ? after adding if you print searcINp.get_attribute('value') what do you get. What do you get if you do searInp.isEnabled()

Comment: The test will crash. Website load too long the element

Comment: website crash ? why would website crash ?

Comment: is the field enabled ?

Comment: Not website the test is failed (my fault use not correct word). I add more detail to the ticket

Comment: please remove the sleep and add the exception it throws

Comment: You set `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);` but you do not use it.

Comment: I used it but this doesn't help
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(searchInp));
      searchInp.click();
      
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(searchInp));
      searchInp.sendKeys(seminarName);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(searchInp, seminarName));
  
    searchInp.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: your xpath isn't very targetted.  If you can, target by id or name.  A click shouldn't be necessary here.  (If it is, the site doesn't allow for tab to set focus... sendKeys will automatically set focus.)

Comment: @pcalkins sendKeys() method works well without method click
The issue is driver works too fast for the website. I found it when looked at the test is finished before the needed info is displayed

Comment: ok, sounds like you need to wait after the enter key... for the DOM to update?  You should use webdriver waits when you grab the data and use more targetted xpaths... right now it's just looking for the2nd cell?...  //td[1].  Target it to find the data after the DOM has updated.  If those are blank values before updating, check for non-blank.  You need an xpath that differentiates before update and after.  Hopefully there are IDs or something unique you can target.